# Input number, then print stairs vertically mirrored

Tags: c++

as in the title.
I could do the easier one, just print them normally, but I have no clue how to mirror them. Here's my code for the "backwards" stairs.

```
    int szam;
    cin >> szam;
    for (int i = 0; i < szam; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

So when the input number is 4, It's printing this,

```
*
**
***
****
```

but i need them mirrored vertically, like this

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

Thanks for the help in advance, and I'd appreciate if you would explain what why happened.

Comment: Add szam-i+1 spaces.

Comment: @arundeepchohan I'm sorry, but could you be more specific? :/

Comment: prior to the 2nd for loop just cout out an empty ' ' szam - i+1 times.

Comment: @arundeepchohan The comments section is not for answers. Put your answer in the answer section where it can go all the usual peer review. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just comes down to arithmetic, really.

1. Study the shape again.
2. Now pretend you're not "mirroring" it, but just adding some whitespace to the start of each line. Because, really, you are.
3. How much whitespace? It starts at 3 for the first line (`i=0`) and ends at 0 for the last line (`i=3`). What's the pattern there?
4. When we work it out, it comes to `szam-1+1` spaces.

Now we can just add those spaces, which is easy:

```
int szam;
cin >> szam;
for (int i = 0; i < szam; i++) {

    // This loop is new
    for (int j = 0; j < szam-1+1; j++) {
        cout << ' ';
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

There are fancier ways using `std::string` or stream formatting, but this is the quick fix to your existing code.

---

Another way, which only involves one inner loop, is to always write `szam` characters but decide within the loop whether those characters should be `*` or a whitespace, again using arithmetic:

```
int szam;
cin >> szam;
for (int i = 0; i < szam; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < szam; j++) {
        cout << (j < szam-i-1 ? ' ' : '*');
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

With this version, your original "unmirrored" output can be obtained by using `(j <= i ? '*' : ' ')`.

---

By the way, you shouldn't use `endl` in a loop — it's pointless. `endl` flushes the stream, whereas you just want a newline. The way to write a newline is `cout << '\n'`.

Also, check `cin >> szam` for success before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks, the "quick fix" version is perfect for me now, -in time i'll advance- especially I appreciate for the explanation (spaces before it, why I didn't think), and thanks for the tips as well. (oh and I don't know if you want to edit it, but you made a typeo, in the first code you wrote szam-1+1)

Comment: @PéterPintér It's one of those "oooooh" moments :P

Answer (score 1):

There are really many many solutions for this problem. I show here an example using a `std::string` to create a string with the reuired number of stars.

I use also IO manipulators. Maybe that is what the teacher wants to see. So, we do right alignment and set a field width.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    // Inform the user what to do
    std::cout << "\nEnter the width of the stair: ";

    // Read the width of the stair and check, if the read operation was successful
    if (unsigned int width{}; std::cin >> width) {

        // Now print the full stair
        for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < width; ++i) {

            // Print stars
            std::cout << std::right << std::setw(width) << std::string(i+1,'*') << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it's a lot to my knowledge. We only learned what <iostream> and namespace std does, so the other 2 are new for me. I don't know, but can't I just do it somehow with modifying what I write in the 2 fors?  arundeep chohan wrote "Add szam-i+1 spaces." ,but I don't know where to put it, or what to modify.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= szam; i++) {
    cout  << string((szam-i),' ')<<string(i,'*') << endl; 
}
```

If you want cout then just do this. The answers are numerous.

Comment: Thanks, it's working well, but we didn't "learn" strings yet. (or at least it isn't yet in the subject structure, where this task is)

Comment: it's a function that just couts a char n times.

Comment: you can replace it with a for loop and cout a empty char.